# How to change location of templates?

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to organize my files, which includes changing the location of some template files. However, I can't seem to get the server to pick up these changes. Restarting the server doesn't do it, nor does makemigrations pick up the change.

I'm going from:

```
class CollapsiblePanelBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    title=blocks.CharBlock()
    body=blocks.StreamBlock([
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
    ])
    class Meta:
        template='base/panel.html'
        icon='folder-inverse'
        label='Collapsible Panel'
```

to:

```
class CollapsiblePanelBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    title=blocks.CharBlock()
    body=blocks.StreamBlock([
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
    ])
    class Meta:
        template='block/panel.html'
        icon='folder-inverse'
        label='Collapsible Panel'
```

But keep getting a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error.

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: base/panel.html
```

Comment: Are you trying to change template path for a streamfield block? Could you, please, update your question with your block definition?

Comment: Full block definition added. Yes, just trying to change the template path.

Comment: Found the issue. A coworker  had added another reference for the same template.